# network configuration not working

Tags: networking, 16.04

Changes under `/etc/network/interfaces` are not considered.

This is set :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.202.131
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.202.2
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

But after reboot, if I do `ifconfig`, I still have the old ens33  :

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:f9:a7:4a
      inet addr:192.168.93.135  Bcast:192.168.93.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::90ab:97d4:31ea:245a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:21403 (21.4 KB)  TX bytes:13645 (13.6 KB)
```

Why is that ?

Comment: ... your interface isn't called `eth0`

Comment: @steeldriver what's the name, "ens33" ?

Comment: Yes it seems so - however if this is a *desktop* version of Ubuntu, you should probably be setting up the interface via the GUI applet, rather than by editing the interfaces file

Comment: If you want to turn off Predictive names so you can go back to eth0, check http://askubuntu.com/a/867533/231142

Answer (score 4):

It does that because the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is only for editing current interfaces. You cannot create a new interface or rename an interface from it.

The correct settings that your gonna wanna use is this:

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.202.131 
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.202.2 
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

The name of the interface being configured in this case is `ens33`. You can get that information form your `ifconfig` command.
The `ens33` on the left of the readout is the name of your interface. This could be `eth0`, `wl0`, `ens33`, etc... The name itself is dynamic and is different for different interfaces (each interface has to be unique, E.g. `eth0`, `eth1` for Ethernet ports 1 and 2). In later versions of Ubuntu the naming schema changed, now `eth0`, `etc...` is a fall back if it cannot reliably name an interface.

---

### links:

If you want to rename your interface, checkout this link:
https://askubuntu.com/a/689143/180773 (warning, advanced)

---

### Tl;Dr:

The interface name is incorrect for your `interfaces` file.

Comment: thanks! I'll check out the link about renaming an interface

Comment: Awesome, you are most likely not going to need to change your interface name. If I answered your question please mark it as solved. Thanks!